# How to convert a String eg 0d-2 or 9.9d-1 as a float number 0.00 or 0.99 in java

Tags: java

I am getting the value as 0d-2 or 9.9d-1. Is there any function available in java to directly convert it into numbers as 0.00 or 0.99 etc..

Comment: There is no build in function for this as this is a custom format.

Comment: Float is a binary number, which doesn't contain info on how many decimal digits of precision it should have. 0 and 0.00 are the same float value.

Answer (score 1):

first you can split your string :

```
String separator = "d";
String[] split = "9.9d-1".split(separator);
```

Then you compute your result :

```
Double result = Double.valueOf(split[0]) * Math.pow(10, Integer.valueOf(split[1]));
```

Please note that this code may throw exceptions when parsing strings to numbers or `IndexOutOfBoundException` when accessing `split[0]` or `split[1]`.

Comment: The `"d"` string is not a regex, thais name is misleading. Something like *separator* should be more appropriate

Comment: yes i agree. edit done !